# Spring Cloud Auth Service Unable to load config data from 'configserver

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, spring-cloud

I have a problem about running **auth service**.

Even if I couldn't determine whether it works, I couldn't run it.

I got the error appearing on the console shown below.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'configserver:http://localhost:9296'
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: File extension is not known to any PropertySourceLoader. If the location is meant to reference a directory, it must end in '/' or File.separator
```

To run the example

1 ) Run Registry Service

2 ) Run config service

3 ) Run API Gateway

4 ) Run other services

Here is the project link : [Project Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/microservicecoursedailybuffer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution.

After I changed the Spring version of auth which is the same as others, the issue disappeared.

Changed

```
<version>2.7.5</version>
```

to

```
<version>2.7.4</version>
```

in `pom.xml`